# Is there something similar to commit for DDL?

Tags: oracle, rollback, ddl

When I want to update, delete, insert I need to commit. That's helpful most of the time, I might update wrong information or delete something by mistake and I can undo that.

When dropping a column, I don't need a commit. Is there something like rollback (not flashback), which enables me to undo my changes quickly? Dropping a column, even after a long analysis can probably cause damage to the table (pk, fk).

Why did Oracle provided a commit for DML but not for DDL?

Comment: Why not flashback? That's one of the things it is for.

Comment: @Mat flashback will not work in case some ddl has been performed on a table

Comment: @beherenow: flashback database will.

Comment: @Mat yes, but it is basically recovering from a backup, isn't it?

Comment: @beherenow: way faster though.

Answer (score 6):

> Why did Oracle provided a commit for DML but not for DDL?

When you issue a DDL statement, you basically start a transaction against the Oracle data dictionary, and this transaction, to eliminate any overheads, has to be as short as possible and take effect as soon as possible. Because of this, DDL statement does double commit, before the DDL statement and then right after(or rollback, if something went wrong) the statement. This behavior makes Oracle's DDL not transactional DDL and you cannot commit or rollback it explicitly. It's just the way it is.

Having said that, if you dropped a table, then starting from 10g and up you can use `flashback table` technology to get it back in one statement, because Oracle, after you issue `drop table` statement wont drop it, it rather puts it in the recycle bin:

```
flashback table <<table_name>> to before drop
```

Unfortunately you cannot use flashback table, to restore a dropped column of a table, simply because dropped column wont be placed in the recycle bin. You will have to perform a point in time recovery of your full database or a single tablespace, or if there is a logical backup(*.dmp file), restore table from it by using `imp` or `impdp` utility.